# xamarin PCL consume WCF: unhandled exception in Android

Tags: c#, wcf, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017

I'm totally new in xamarin.

I use Visual Studio 2017 Community and I write a very simple code: I want to connect to a basic WCF service.

The link to the service:

http://services.adserviceitalia.it/Service1.svc

(method GetHello, input string and return string... very basic method)

I read a lot of samples... I add a reference to the services, generate the proxy class... ok!!

```
 public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{

  private  wcfs.Service1Client ws;


    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();


        var endpoint = new EndpointAddress("http://services.adserviceitalia.it/Service1.svc");
        var binding = new BasicHttpBinding
        {
           Name = "basicHttpBinding",
          MaxBufferSize = 2147483647,
           MaxReceivedMessageSize = 2147483647
       };
         TimeSpan timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30);
      binding.SendTimeout = timeout;
        binding.OpenTimeout = timeout;
   binding.ReceiveTimeout = timeout;

        ws = new wcfs.Service1Client(binding,endpoint);
        ws.GetHelloCompleted += Handle_HelloWorldCompleted;

    }

    private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        ws.GetHelloAsync("Mark");

      }


    private void Handle_HelloWorldCompleted(object sender, wcfs.GetHelloCompletedEventArgs args)
    {

        label1.Text =   args.Result;
    }

    }
}
```

It works in UWP debug...

[Connection with WCF... Hello World working in UWP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tqqv2.png)

I got an unhandled exception in Android...

In Android Manifest all permission are cheched. The Android emulator is connected to internet...

Every help would be extremely appreciated!! Thanks in advance... and excuse me form my english.

Comment: what is the exception that occurs in Android?

Comment: I don't know... :-(((
It appear a window only: "An unhandled exception occured"

Without refs

Comment: hit break - then use the debugger to look at the exception and stack trace

Comment: I've problem to accomplish this task.
The exception fire in line:

 ws.GetHelloAsync("Mark");

I can produce some screenshots... but poor of informations :-(

http://imgur.com/a/zuxrT

Comment: You need to learn how to use the debugger.  Examining the Exception object should allow you to see the exception being returned by the server - probably in the InnerException property

Comment: I try to wrap code in a try - catch block... believe me, i don't know how examine the exception... in desktop and web develop all the exceptions have full detail... :((

Comment: @treep Hello treep, I once had a similiar problem like yours, because Xamarin.Android had problems with ConnectTimeout. You can comment the timeout lines and see if works

Answer (score 0):

Ops...

First: thanks to all!!

In my log i read this: 
04-27 14:11:30.106 E/mono-rt ( 5308): [ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: Android.Util.AndroidRuntimeException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

Seems that problem is that I try to update the interface directly in Handle_HelloWorldCompleted with WCF respose:

```
 label1.Text =   args.Result;
```

... in I modify the code in this way:

```
 //label1.Text =   args.Result;
 System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(args.Result);
```

I can see that arg.Result is populated by the WCF response "Hola Mark" (ergo: the connection with the service works!!) .

Notice i've this behavior in Android debug only.

How I can update that label1 ??

Comment: Thanks Jason. ;-)
This works:
  Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>  { label1.Text =   args.Result;});
I don't know how implement Activity.RunOnUiThread. Is very different??

Comment: Thanks Jason. I appreciate that you've spent some time to help me. I am completely new to the environment.